# Add case statement in insert query to turn empty string into null

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

I am trying to insert values from an Excel VBA userform to MySQLDBA.
The problem comes with empty text box values for date columns.
MySQL doesn't accept " but it allows Null.

Can I add a case statement in my insert query to check if the value for the column is empty string, and if it is, insert null for that column? Otherwise, it should insert the value of the textbox.

Here is my current query in VBA, where Date_of_Birth columns should be checked for empty string:

```
Str = "insert into sample.details (ID,Name,Age,Gender,Date_of_Birth) values ('" & txt1.Value & "', '" & txt2.Value & "','" & txt3.Value & "','" & txt4.Value & "','" & txt5.Value & "');"
```

P.S I tried setting a if condition for the txt5.value but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `IIf` function.

```
Str = "insert into sample.details (ID,Name,Age,Gender,Date_of_Birth) values ('" & txt1.Value & "', '" & txt2.Value & "','" & txt3.Value & "','" & txt4.Value & "'," & IIf(txt5.Value="","null","'" & txt5.Value & "'") & ");"
```

Comment: Thank you, I've been trying to get this work for two days...I was lucky to have you read my question...Cheers mate!!! :)

Comment: No problem! Glad I was here to help!